# Error while deploying hello1 web module to glassfish, from java tutorials

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-7

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/webapp003.htm) from the java ee documentation and I'm trying to deploy a simple web module to the glasfish server.

> 6.3.2.1 To Build and Package the hello1 Web Module Using NetBeans IDE
>
> 1. Start GlassFish Server as described in To Start GlassFish Server Using
>      NetBeans IDE, if you have not already done so.
> 2. From the File menu, choose Open Project.
> 3. In the Open Project dialog box, navigate to:
>      *tut-install*/examples/web/jsf
> 4. Select the hello1 folder.
> 5. Click Open Project.
> 6. In the Projects tab, right-click the hello1 project and select Build.
>      This command deploys the project to the server.

When I clicked `Build`, it failed and gave me the following error

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 26.227s
Finished at: Thu Apr 05 11:38:32 IST 2018
Final Memory: 11M/80M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (deploy) on project hello1: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [glassfish5x], type = [installed]], configuration type [existing]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I downloaded javaEE and  did everything just as they instructed in the tutorial, why am I getting an error?

Comment: You should change the **java-ee-8** tag for your question to **java-ee-7**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Glassfish 5 which did not exist when the EE7 tutorial was written.

Try [downloading and installing the latest version of Glassfish 4](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download) (version 4.1.2), and use that instead of Glassfish 5.

It's definitely worth verifying that your installation of Glassfish 4 is working before resuming the tutorial:

- Start the Glassfish 4 server and enter http://localhost:4848 in your browser.
- You should see the Glassfish 4.x admin console as shown below.
- Click the **About** button in the top left to verify the version.

[image: glassfishAdmin]

Answer (score 0):

I updated cargo version in pom.xml (glassfish5\docs\javaee-tutorial\examples\pom.xml):
`<cargo.plugin.version>1.8.4</cargo.plugin.version>`